# Spinner doesn't show data when selected, also shows the spinner data lately

Tags: android, spinner

I am using a spinner that loads the value from making a **GET** request to my web server.
But the problem is that the spinner does show the loaded value (though lately), but doesn't show the selected value.
[spinner image after selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOqT6.png)

I checked the background color. Tried running the code on UI Thread, but it doesn't work.

```
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/setup_wizard_spinner_year"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
        </Spinner>
```

The activity

```
    adapterYear = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, viewModel.getData("Year"));
    iYearSpinner.setAdapter(adapterYear);
```

The method

```
public List<String> getData(String query){
    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    String URL = "mysite.com?query=" + query;
    List<String> spinnerDataList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(URL)
                        .build();
    httpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                String webResponse = response.body().string();
                JSONArray jsonArray = null;
                try {
                    jsonArray = new JSONArray(webResponse);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                    spinnerDataList.add(jsonArray.optString(i));
                }

            }
        }
    });
    return spinnerDataList;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed: 
Populate the data in UiThread, make the network call in another thread. Wait till the thread is finished executing.
It may slow the apps, but I was OK with that, used handler to show spinner as my next task is depended more upon on what data I get and select.

Answer (score 1):

You're fetching the `spinnerDataList` from the internet, it'll take time to get the data.

Try returning LiveData and observe it in the Activity and then set the list to the adapter.

You're using `R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item` instead use `R.layout.support_simple_spinner_item` in the ArrayAdapter constructor.

Set the layout resource to create dropdown views
`adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)`

Comment: I have used LiveData later, but the problem is still the same. It doesn't show anything unless I'm populating data in MainUiThread.